# netplan with multiple vlans on single interface - help needed

Tags: networking, netplan

I have a single virtual interface and 802.1q enabled. When I have a single vlan for my interface in netplan it works, but when I add a second, additional vlan only the last vlan in the file works, preceding vlans do not. Here is the config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens0:
      match:
        name: ens160
vlans:
  vlan.45:
    id: 45
    link: ens0
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [ 10.0.45.11/24 ]
    gateway: 10.0.45.1
    nameservers:
      search: [ domain.local ]
      addresses: [ 8.8.8.8 ]
  vlan.110:
    id: 110
    link: ens0
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [ 10.0.11.103/24 ]
    gateway: 10.0.11.1
    nameservers:
      search: [ domain.local ]
      addresses: [ 10.0.11.18 ]
```

Answer (score 17):

The following works for me to define two vlans on one physical interface:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            addresses: 
                - 192.168.122.201/24
            gateway4: 192.168.122.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.122.1]
        ens8: {}

    vlans:
        vlan.101:
            id: 101
            link: ens8
            addresses: [192.168.101.1/24]
        vlan.102:
            id: 102
            link: ens8
            addresses: [192.168.102.1/24]
```

Notice, the `vlan` section is at the same level of indent as the `ethernets` key.  Both are contained within `network`.

`ip link` to show result:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:e4:bc:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ens8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7e:d5:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vlan.101@ens8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7e:d5:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vlan.102@ens8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7e:d5:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Thank you @dpb. I ended up using a different OS but if this comes up again I will try your suggestion.