# How to use DHCP on multiple VLANs on a single interface with netplan?

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, vlan

In my current network topology I have multiple VLANs - each of which has it's own routing:

```
VLAN 10:
  DHCP:    10.0.10.10-10.0.10.255
  Subnet:  255.255.255.0
  Gateway: 10.0.10.1

VLAN 11
  DHCP:    10.0.11.10-10.0.11.255
  Subnet:  255.255.255.0
  Gateway: 10.0.11.1
```

The machine(s) I'm automatically provisioning have a single NIC.
This is why I would like to avoid using static configurations and rather relay on the DHCP to provide the "correct" settings.

My yaml looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      # Designate the connection as "critical to the system", meaning that special care will be taken by systemd-networkd 
      # to not release the IP from DHCP when it the daemon is restarted.
      critical: yes
      dhcp4: no

  vlans:
    cloud:
      id: 10
      link: enp5s0
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 200

    office:
      id: 11
      link: enp5s0
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 100
```

The problem is it only gets the DHCP settings for the `cloud` vlan and does nothing with the `office` one. Am I missing something here?

NOTE:
This is not a duplicate of [netplan with multiple vlans on single interface - help needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992428/netplan-with-multiple-vlans-on-single-interface-help-needed).

Comment: Are you sure the line you're connected to on enp5s0 is carrying VLAN 10 to your system?  Not getting DHCP for a VLAN typically means it's not properly communicating on the network, usually when the specific VLAN ID is not properly transferred down from the network link

Comment: @ThomasWard yes, I'm sure. If I have only one VLAN in the configuration and switch between `id: 10` and `id: 11` it works just fine and I receive the DHCP configuration. It doesn't seem to be that. If I set `entp5s0` to `dhcp4: yes` and then have only the `cloud` VLAN it works again. It specifically doesn't work when I add a second VLAN like the configuration above for some reason. :/

Answer (score 0):

Remember, your DHCP-server does not know about your VLAN configurations.

It is getting a request for an IP for the MAC-adress of enp5s0 and then another request, most likely identical to the previous request. Have a look at the DHCP log, it should confirm this. Or use tcpdump to debug the traffic.

Comment: This answer assumes there's only a single DHCP server.  That is not at all obvious; typically if you are going to have multiple networks with different subnets, the DHCP server on each is a different machine.